# Does the bitwise operators XOR and OR works differently on negative numbers unlike AND operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I was trying various combination for better understanding of the XOR operator but I am not able to figure out how bitwise actually works under the hood in case of negative numbers because it's fine(as expected) in the case of positive numbers but producing different results in case of bitwise AND(&), bitwise XOR(^) and bitwise OR(|) case while applying the same logic for negative numbers.

In case of positive numbers:

```
x = 26;
y = 3;
System.out.println(x ^ y); // 25
System.out.println(x & y); // 2
System.out.println(x | y); // 27

11010 -> 26
00011 -> 3

Applying XOR    Applying AND    Applying OR
11010           11010           11010
00011           00011           00011
-----           -----           -----
11001 -> 25     00010 -> 2      11011 -> 27
```

Expected outputs as when analysing manually.

But, in case of negative number:

```
x = 26;
y = -3;
System.out.println(x ^ y); // -25
System.out.println(x & y); // 24
System.out.println(x | y); // -1


00000000000000000000000000011010 --> 26
11111111111111111111111111111101 --> -3(2s complement of -3)

         Applying XOR                            Applying OR       
00000000000000000000000000011010       00000000000000000000000000011010            
11111111111111111111111111111101       11111111111111111111111111111101            
--------------------------------       --------------------------------        
11111111111111111111111111100111       11111111111111111111111111111111
```

(not expected outputs because while analysing manually it's giving different output because if I will convert the result of XOR(11111111111111111111111111100111) and OR(11111111111111111111111111111111) into decimal, then it will give a huge number which is nowhere nearby the expected output)

Any suggestions what internally is being done with which I am not familiar with or the functionality of bitwise XOR(|), AND(&) and OR(|) under the hood in case of negative numbers

Comment: Why do you think 11010 can mean 26 while 11101 can mean -3 in the same representation? Either both are negative or neither is negative.

Comment: In other words, your arbitrary decision to represent the numbers with 5 bits instead of 32 is having you miss some crucial context about those numbers.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am aware that they are represented with 32 bits and if I apply zeros and ones at front and do XOR or OR operations on bits of 26 and -3, even then I am not getting the expected output when analysing it manually.

Comment: @Michael I have edited my question and thank you for the suggestion as It was a bit confusing...

Comment: What **do** you expect the results of the negative numbers to be? You present us what the results are but don't tell us why you expect them to be different or what you expect them to be.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I just want to know where I am going wrong when applying XOR or OR operator on bits of 26 and -3 manually...that's it and nothing else...

Comment: @AkshayaAmar: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Why do you think you are? What do you think `11111111111111111111111111100111` interpreted as a Java `int` (i.e. a signed 32 bit integer) is in decimal?

Comment: @AkshayaAmar, could you also show the code that you use to convert between decimal and binary? Seems like the problem should be there. When I try your numbers I don't get huge numbers. I get -1 and -25.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev There is no such problem with the code and even I am getting the expected results as -1 & -25 but when applying XOR or OR bitwise operator manually on the binary of 25 and -3 and when try to convert the binary form output into decimal manually((1bit for signed)and then 1*(2 ^ 30) + 1*(2 ^ 29)..........0*(2 ^ 4) + 1*(2 ^ 3) + 1*(2 ^ 1) + 1*(2 ^ 0)), then I am getting such huge number...so I just want to know if I am doing something wrong while solving it manually

Comment: Okay, so the problem is NOT with the code. The problem is the calculation that you're doing in your head. Correct formula: `-2^32 + (2^31 + 2^30 + ...)`. For negative number the 1st out of 32 bits is filled. So you _subtract_ the 1st (negative) bit from the rest of bits. Why weren't you surprised that `-3` is also a huge number in binary according to your formula?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Even that was not the problem...the actual problem was not converting the binary output(produced after applying XOR) into 2's form and then do the decimal conversion as I was converting the binary output straight to the decimal..I was only aware that negative number is first converted to 1s and then 2s while storing numbers in memory but was not aware of the fact that while retrieving also it is converted back into 2s and then the decimal operation is performed. @ Joachim Sauer cleared my doubt in one of his answers...

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev: shouldn't be the mentioned formula be like this: -2 ^ 31 + (2 ^ 30 + 2 ^ 29 + ....) as operation is being performed on negative number i.e. signed integer is used here and not unsigned and the result will be -25(as expected) in case of XOR operator using formula i.e. -2147483648(via -2 ^ 31) + 2147483623 = -25

Comment: @AkshayaAmar, oops, my mistake

Answer (score 4):

It is how numbers are stored internally when they are negative. For example:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(26));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-3));
```

will output:

```
0000000.............0000...11010 // the zeros in front are not shown
11111111111111111111111111111101
```

So now it should make sense what happens when you `XOR` or `AND`. They are represented with `32 bits`, that is where your miss-understanding is.

Comment: I am aware that they are represented with 32 bits and if I apply zeros and ones at front and do XOR or OR operations on bits of 26 and -3, even then I am not getting the expected output when analysing it manually. You can check the same with your provided output and apply XOR operation on them(binary digits of 26 and -3) and try converting them into decimal (by doing them manually)

Comment: @AkshayaAmar: I think your mistake is that you convert them to decimal assuming they are *usigned*! (i.e. straight binary-to-decimal conversion), but they are of course signed. That means you must consider the sign bit and take the 2s complement (as you alluded to in your question). `11111111111111111111111111100111` is of course `-25` and not "some huge number".

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have not converted the decimal into binary straight away...first I took out the 1s compliment by reversing the binary and then 2s by adding 1 to the reversed binary and then start performing operation(XOR or OR) on them and I am too getting -25 (programmatically) when applying ^ on both the operands but I am not able to convert and get the desired output of -25 when manually converting the binary output into decimal which is turning out to be a big number

Comment: @JoachimSauer When converting decimal to binary i.e. System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-25)) is giving 11111111111111111111111111100111(which is expected) but reverse(binary back to decimal) by System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1111111111111111111111111100111", 2)); is producing 2147483623(big number) instead of -25

Comment: @JoachimSauer You are absolutely right I was converting the binary straight to the decimal...I was only aware that negative number is first converted to 1s and then 2s while storing numbers in memory but was not aware of the fact that while retrieving also it is converted back into 2s and then the decimal operation is performed. Thank you so much clarifying this issue which I was lacking...greateful to you...

Comment: @AkshayaAmar: it should be noted that one *could* just write `-11001` to represent -25 in binary, but that notation is very rare, because it doesn't actually help: Binary is tricky for humans to use and when computers use them, they use the 2s complement (i.e. they don't have a `-` symbol, they just need to know that a given 32 bit value is meant to be interpreted as signed). So `toBinaryString` effectively outputs the "unsigned binary" (i.e. interpreting the bits as if they where unsigned), which happens to be how they are actually stored in memory.